# Why my inner join is not working properly in the following DB struture

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

I'm working in a project where I'm using a EAV structure and when I'm querying my data from tables , the inner join is not working properly .

**DB STRUCTURE**

I've four tables .

- Records
- Forms
- Fields
- FieldValues
- Records have FormID (So we can get the form basically we have
  different services as a forms).
- Fields have FormID (Different forms have different fields like name ,
  location etc)
- FieldValues have RecordID and FieldID (We have so many request of
  same form so we can get the values of all fields of the record from
  here)

[image: See the attached image for better understanding]

Now When I'm writing the query .

```
SELECT R.RecordID RID,  R.CreatedOn CO,R.FormID ,               
(Select ServiceNameEn From InstakinServices where InstakinServiceID = IIF(ISNUMERIC(FV. 
 [Data]) = 1, REPLACE(FV.[Data],'.' , '') , 0)) [Service]
,(Select NameEn From Cities where CityID = IIF(ISNUMERIC(FVC.[Data]) = 1, REPLACE(FVC. 
 [Data],'.' , '') , 0)) City
FROM Records R
INNER JOIN Forms F ON F.FormID = R.FormID
INNER JOIN FieldValues FV ON FV.RecordID = R.RecordID AND FV.FieldID = (SELECT FieldID 
FROM Fields WHERE FormID = R.FormID AND FieldName = 'SelectService')
INNER JOIN FieldValues FVC ON FVC.RecordID = R.RecordID AND FVC.FieldID = (SELECT FieldID FROM Fields WHERE FormID = R.FormID AND FieldName = 'SelectCity')
```

Query Details :

I'm joining the records table with forms with FormID
And than I'm joining the Fieldvalues table to get the values of city and service fields.
I've integer values present in fieldvalues against these two fields , but when I'm querying it is showing me an error `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '110.00' to data type int` . 110.00 is not present in any fiedvalues of city and service fields 110.00 is the quoated amount fields which have differnet FieldID and FieldName, why I'm getting this error ?

Note : I'm using Replace in above query by this it is working fine , but when I don't use replace it is showing me the error . why ? any idea??

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions givea a [mre]. . When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation.  Ask 1 question. [ask] [help]

Comment: You can probably resolve this by replacing your `iif(isnumeric...` with `try_cast()`

Comment: I'm lost at the first sentence.  What is a dynamic database structure?

Comment: Help us out: do a select * instead and post up the results

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to decode the problem without actual data, but i suspect that if you clean up your query to the format like below, you can troubleshoot easily.

```
SELECT 
    R.RecordID RID,  
    R.CreatedOn CO,
    R.FormID ,               
    II.ServiceNameEn [Service],
    C.NameEn City
FROM Records R
    INNER JOIN Forms F 
        ON F.FormID = R.FormID
    INNER JOIN Fields FF
        ON FF.FormID= R.FormID
    INNER JOIN FieldValues FV 
        ON FV.RecordID = R.RecordID 
        AND FV.FieldID =  FF.FieldID
        AND FieldName = 'SelectService'
    INNER JOIN FieldValues FVC
        ON FVC.RecordID = R.RecordID 
        AND FVC.FieldID =  FF.FieldID
        AND FieldName ='SelectCity'
    LEFT JOIN Cities C
        ON C.CityID = IIF(ISNUMERIC(FVC.[Data]) = 1, FVC.[Data], 0)
    LEFT JOIN InstakinServices II
        ON II.InstakinServiceID = IIF(ISNUMERIC(FV.[Data]) = 1, FV.[Data], 0)
```

Note : What you have is called an EAV structure. best way to query an eav structure avoiding multiple joins is to pivot out the data from fieldvalues and then use that in join.

Comment: I'm unable to understand when I'm joining it with the field having fieldname service and citi so why It is showing me the error that I can not bind 110.00 which is the value of another field instead of service and city , it means the inner join is not working properly ?

Comment: Avoid `ISNUMERIC`, use `TRY_CAST` instead. For example `ISNUMERIC('-.')` returns 1